# How to restore `mathsf` to LaTeX default (i.e. CM Sans)?

Tags: fonts

A publication template sets `mathsf` to use an ugly font. How can change it to use CM Sans font instead?

Towards the same goal, `\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathcal}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}` did the trick for resetting `mathcal` font.

Comment: `\DeclareMathAlphabet      {\mathsf}{OT1}{cmss}{m}{n}` but the whole point of publication classes is that the publisher not the author chooses the style, so changing the font seems completely wrong

Comment: You will just annoy the person who has to undo your 'improvements' to the house style. If you aren't tied to that house style, don't use the template, of course. Note that some publishers set fonts up to give you an idea of the finished result, because the fonts they use in the end are not freely available. The final version uses their fonts; the fonts configured in the template are just approximations in terms of the space they take etc. But, if you need to use this template, don't change the house style.